# convert Pdf to png create Black margin around image

Tags: c#, png, ghostscript.net

I'm trying to convert pdf to image with ghostscript.net (1.2.1.0) and gs version is 9.22 x86.

my code:

```
using (_rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
{
    _rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, _lastInstalledVersion, false);

    //_rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-sDEVICE=pngalpha");
    //_rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-dTextAlphaBits=4");
    //_rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4");

    for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= _rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
    {
        var desiredDPI = 102;
        using (System.Drawing.Image img = _rasterizer.GetPage(desiredDPI, desiredDPI, pageNumber))
        {
            img.Save(pageNumber + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

it works for some pages, but for some images, it create black margin and black background.

sample files:
[pdf](https://nofile.io/f/2E8jTNEHDwe/b.pdf) => [png](https://nofile.io/f/AFJSJZNTf71/b.png)

I test with gs command, it was ok.
I tried following code. images was good but text was low quality.

```
public Image getImg(string inputFile, int pageNO, int resolution)
{
    GhostscriptPngDevice dev = new GhostscriptPngDevice(GhostscriptPngDeviceType.PngAlpha);
    dev.GraphicsAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
    dev.TextAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
    dev.ResolutionXY = new GhostscriptImageDeviceResolution(resolution, resolution);
    dev.InputFiles.Add(inputFile);
    dev.Pdf.FirstPage = pageNO;
    dev.Pdf.LastPage = pageNO;
    dev.CustomSwitches.Add("-dDOINTERPOLATE");
    dev.OutputPath = pageNO + ".png";
    dev.Process();

    return Image.FromFile(pageNO + ".png");
}
```

Comment: When you say you tested "gs command" do you mean that you ran Ghostscript from the command line, and got the expected result ?

Comment: yes. comand was `gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -ob.png -r105 b.pdf`

Comment: Well, if Ghostscript works from the command line, then it must be something in the framework (though I can't see what). One possibility; are you using the same version of Ghostscript in both cases ?

Comment: yes. they are same version. I test `GhostscriptProcessor` and it works too. It seems something in `GhostscriptRasterizer` happens. thank you @Kens. I think use `GhostscriptProcessor` and dirct access to ghostscript.

Comment: Can I just say thanks for saving my ass with this code. I was using a GhostScriptRasterizer object instead and any PDF imported was exporting with black text on black backgrounds, rendering my attempts useless and a major showstopper in my customers' application. This (with a couple of slight alterations) works perfectly for my uses. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
 GhostscriptPngDevice dev = new GhostscriptPngDevice(GhostscriptPngDeviceType.Png16m);
        dev.GraphicsAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
        dev.TextAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
        dev.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        dev.ResolutionXY = new GhostscriptImageDeviceResolution(desired_x_dpi, desired_y_dpi);
        dev.InputFiles.Add(inputPathAndFile);
        dev.Pdf.FirstPage = 1;
        dev.Pdf.LastPage = 1;
        dev.CustomSwitches.Add("-dDOINTERPOLATE");
        dev.OutputPath = outputPathAndFile;
        dev.Process();
```